# ANTLR 4: How do I know if all the input was parsed?

Tags: antlr4

If my input is "ab" and the parse is looking for "a", it recognises "a" as expected but I need the trailing "b" to produce an error. How do I test for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lexer generates an EOF token at the end of the source input. To force processing of all input, require the EOF as part of your main parser rule:

```
r : a+ EOF ;
a : A ;
b : B ;
A : 'a' ;
B : 'b' ;
```

The parser, starting from rule `r` with input 'abaab', will throw an unrecognized input error - actually two. The default parser error strategy will attempt to skip a limited number of consecutive unknown tokens - one IIRC - and try to resynchronize with the input token stream. In this case it will succeed in resynchronizing, first with an A token and second with the EOF token.

Optionally, use

1. Parser.addErrorListener(...) to add your own error reporter (extend BaseErrorListener)
2. Parser.setErrorHandler(...) to add your own error recovery strategy (extend DefaultErrorStrategy)

Comment: Yup that's it. For some reason since I switch to V4 of ANTLR I've dropped the EOF. I'm getting old. Thanks GRose.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly you can use [actions](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Actions+and+Attributes) inside your Antlr grammar which will looks something like:

```
grammar Expr;       
prog:   a b;
a:  'a';
b: 'b'{throw new Exception();};
```

Which will throw an error after the parser has seen a valid declaration of b. Instead of throwing an error you can also print out some debugging information.

Comment: Thanks. The grammar is, of course, more complicated than my example.I would need to test for any character except white space and comments as I don't know what comes afterwards. I also don't want to embed java in the .g4 file so that it will work with other languages if possible.

Comment: I believe handling whitespaces is typically done by a rule like `WS: [ \n\t\r]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);`. I'm not sure if actions are supported in other languages than Java.